# Is the expression "You the Man" gender neutral?

Tags: expressions, figures-of-speech

The expression "***You The Man***" is generally used to compliment a male. 
Can this expression be used to compliment a female? If not, what is a suitable alternative?

Comment: Yes, it can be; yes, I have used it thus. No, not everyone will like it, but someone will always take exception to something. Perhaps take your audience into consideration.

Comment: When said to a woman it needs to be with a certain sense of humor.  But if the woman is a feminist to any significant degree it could count as a strong complement.  (OTOH, if the attribute being praised is, say, her looks, and she's NOT a feminist, then it could be taken as a serious insult.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"You go, girl!" is one alternative, with similar connotations and sociolect, that could be used with females.

Comment: I agree that "you the man" is not gender-neutral, and that "you go, girl" is a good gender-swapped analogue.  I also think that both phrases bear an indelible taint of cultural appropriation and haven't been acceptable for non-ironic use since about 1996 at the latest.

Comment: Of course, saying "you go girl" to a guy would strongly imply that you think he's gay.